# remote-access from Unix operator

Tags: unix, ssh, authorization, remote-access, remote-host

Other posts have talked about using      **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** to change the authorization settings.

What Authorization settings should I set my      **sshd_config**      be on if I want this password to connect?

```
  jacobs-mbp:~ nuevo$ ssh  username@141.158.1.6          
  The authenticity of host '141.158.1.6 (142.158.1.6)' can't be established.       
  RSA key fingerprint is b1:0b:cn:o7:6b:f1:22:c5:x5:d1:f8:d2:63:d8:b2:2l.  
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes  
  Warning: Permanently added '141.158.1.6' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.  
  Password:  
  Password:  
  Password:  
  Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap15sec122.html

Comment: At `/private/etc/sshd_config` ?

Comment: ^ that right there is a good answer. I am glad you clarified /private/

Comment: Can you also  describe how to change password authorization from 'no' to 'yes' using a command in the terminal?

Comment: Are you asking WHAT you need to change? Or HOW to change it using terminal?

Comment: `cd /private/etc/sshd_config` then `ls` just to look at settings. How do you switch settings on and off?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to change it:

```
su
Password:
cd /private/etc
vi sshd_config
```

Now type this to search for `PasswordAuthentication`:

```
/PasswordAuth    <Enter>
```

Now press `h` a few times to move to the very left of the line and you are on the `#`

Now press `x` to delete the `#`

Now type the following to write and quit:

```
:wq  <Enter>
```

If you get stuck or lost at any point in the editor, type the following to quit without saving

```
:q!    <Enter>
```

Comment: the second I press `x` I get `W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
E325: ATTENTION       Press ENTER or type command to continue` then when i `:wq` it returns `E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)`

Comment: Try using this to save and quit     `:wq!   <Enter>`

Comment: `"sshd_config" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue` is vi similar to emacs and nano?

Comment: Did you do the `su` at the start in order to become root?

Comment: yahh it returned `su: Sorry`

Comment: That means you got the password wrong... you'll have to try again.

Comment: when I use `sudo` commands my password works but with `su`it should work but doesn't.

Comment: Oh, ok. Just use `sudo sh` to become root.

Comment: Ok, I have successfully removed the `#` but I still can not `ssh username@host`  because of the original problem still. Instead of removing the `#` do you think edited the `no`  to `yes` can simply be the solution to the problem?

Comment: You probably need to restart the `sshd`. If you don;t know how to do that with `launchctl`, I would just reboot so that the new `sshd_config` gets read.

Comment: In order to remotely access my friends computer using `ssh username@ip` and being able to have his password connect is to delete that one `#`?

Comment: Basically you need a line with `PasswordAuthentication yes` to be in your config file `without a hash (#) in front of it` for password authentication to be permitted.

Comment: I can no longer experiment with these changes. My computer cant turn on anymore. I get directed to the ? folder blinking. Already tried repairing nothing is able to work. Going to the apple store fml. If you got any suggestions of how to fix my problem in the terminal please let me know

Comment: You could try starting in Safe Mode http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: It is funny because I got a new computer and i can easily      ssh username@IP         to gain remote access but it will not work with my old computer. Also I went to apple and they had to replace the cable connected to the hard drive.